how to add reference without affect the numbering in bibliography?
When I add a reference to the list of references, the numbering of the references changes, even if I replace one with the other, the numbering changes
How do I add or delete a reference without changing the numbering?
Because I put the number of some references on the pictures, and when I added a reference, everything changed
I want to number some references. For example, I give one designated reference the number 2 and the other 7 so that it matches the numbers in the pictures.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Mybib}


It is easier to edit the images changing the numbers.  And never use numbered references in images to avoid problems like this, its better to use full cite or an author year alternative. Another alternative should be to not hardcode the reference in the image and use LaTeX to add it (using tikzpicture overlays or any similar alternative

Are you hard-coding the numeric values of the cites in the captions? If so, why? Have you considered using \cite directives in the \caption commands as well?

Off-topic: (i) Unless you have failed to update your TeX distribution for five or more years, you don't have to run \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} (as that's been the default for the past five years at least. (ii) top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm may be expressed more succinctly as vmargin=2.5cm. (iii) No need to specify the pdftex option when loading hyperref; in fact, specifying this option could be counterproductive in some circumstances.

The question is very unclear. There would be a problem with the unsrt style: if you have citation callouts in the captions and print the list of figures, then those callouts would end up to be the first appearance. But with plain the reference are sorted in alphabetical order and this is independent on where the callouts are. Of course you should never type directly the reference number, but always use \cite.
